# Вывод ошибок в discord

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

У меня есть код:

````
@client.event
async def on_command_error(event, *args, **kwargs):    
    channel = client.get_channel(727801516626542634)
    embed = discord.Embed(title=':x: Event Error', colour=0xe74c3c) #Red
    embed.add_field(name='Event', value=event)
    embed.description = f'```py\n%s\n```' % traceback.format_exc()
    embed.timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
    await channel.send(embed=embed)
````

Он должен выводить ошибки из консоли в чат, но он делает это очень странно:
[спойлер](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3WUrF.png)

Comment: Приложите картинку в сам вопрос, а не по ссылке (в правке есть иконка изображения).

Comment: что именно странно?

Comment: Мне требуется вывод текстом, а не непонятными символами

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Событие [`on_command_error`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot.on_command_error) ***не*** имеет аргумента `event`. Так же, оно срабатывает при ошибке команды, а не при ошибке события. Для событий и остальных ошибок используйте событие [`on_error`](http://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.on_error)

````py
@client.event
async def on_command_error(ctx, exception): # для команд
    channel = client.get_channel(727801516626542634)
    embed = discord.Embed(title=':x: Command Error', colour=0xe74c3c) #Red
    embed.add_field(name='Command', value=ctx.command)
    embed.description = f"```py\n{traceback.format_exception(type(exception), exception, exception.__traceback__)}\n```"
    embed.timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
    await channel.send(embed=embed)

@client.event
async def on_error(event, *args, **kwargs): # для остальных ошибок   
    channel = client.get_channel(727801516626542634)
    embed = discord.Embed(title=':x: Event Error', colour=0xe74c3c) #Red
    embed.add_field(name='Event', value=event)
    embed.description = f"```py\n{traceback.format_exc()}\n```"
    embed.timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
    await channel.send(embed=embed)
````

*Нет никакого смысла использовать %-форматирование при использовании f-строк.*